# What means $h$ which appears following cosmological measured parameters?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, notation, big-bang, nucleosynthesis

For example, Big Bang Nucleossynthesis says that baryonic content in the Universe is around $0.018 \leq \Omega_{b}h^{2} \leq 0.024$. I know it is something related to measurement error but I do not where it comes from. Someone knows?

Comment: Dimensionless Hubble parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$h$ is a dimensionless version of the Hubble parameter $H_0$:

$$H_0=h\times 100\text{ km s}^{-1}\text{ Mpc}^{-1}$$

(See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law#Dimensionless_Hubble_parameter).)

For example, $h=0.7$ means that the Hubble parameter is 70 kilometers per second per megaparsec.

Comment: Fast and precise. Thanks!

Comment: The check mark lets you “accept” an answer.